# In python, what happens, will the length of a list decrease if I add part of the list to another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider this list here:

```
example=[]
```

And another:

```
python=["hi","bye","hello","yes","no"]
```

If I decide to add one of the elements from python to example, will a duplicate of that element b created or will the variable python lose an element.

```
example+=[python[0]]
```

So would the string "hi" be duplicated or transferred to example using the aforementioned example

Comment: When you run it does the variable python lose an element?

Comment: You may find this description useful: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `example += [python[0]]`. What you have now treats `'hi'` as an iterable and appends each element to `example`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will be no "transfer". This is easy enough to check, by just printing the values after the operation.

Instead, the list example will have appended to it the elements of the first string:

```
>>> f = []
>>> f+= ["hi", "there"][0]
>>> f
['h', 'i']
```

This happens because `a += b` is conceptually* equivalent to `a = a+b`, and `a+b` creates a list which has all the elements of `a` followed by the elements of `b`. A string is sequence, the elements of which are strings composed of individual characters, which is why you get this behaviour.

`*` There are differences, notably that `list + nonlist` won't work.

Comment: Note that `f += "hi"` will work while `f = f + "hi"` will not.

Answer (score 2):

The string "hi" will be split into chars and assigned to `example` when you do `example+=python[0]`

So `example` in this case will contain `['h','i']`.

Also, the list `python` will not lose an element.

Comment: I checked, and the string in python[0] will be split into chars when you do `example+=python[0]`

Answer (score 0):

> > So would the string "hi" be duplicated or transferred?

No, the string `"hi"` will neither be duplicated nor transferred. Rather, the length of the object to which `example` is bound will increase by one, and the reference `example[0]` will be bound to whatever object `python[0]` was bound to. Additionally, neither the reference `python` nor the object to which it is bound will be modified.

Note also, that your question has an error in the example. Where you actually said,

```
example += python[0]
```

You surely meant t say:

```
example += [python[0]]
```

Comment: Downvoter: Yes, my answer is incorrect for the question as stated. I answered the question he meant to ask, instead.

Answer (score 0):

A Python list stores only references to the elements. The elements (here the strings) are stored as outside objects.

Any Python assignment only copies a reference value. This way, the list is implemented as a dynamic array that stores references.

If you insert a string to a list, the source string object is not copied, only the reference to the same object is copied. The source element (here `python[0]`) is not removed from the list `python` when used on the right side of the assignment. It is only read and left untouched.

Answer (score -2):

You have to do the following
example.append(python[0]
That will take the 'hi' and copy to example